# Java при компиляции код хочет java 7 или выше, а у меня стоит 8, как быть?

Tags: java

При компиляции выводиться такое сообщение:

```
com/javacodegeeks/jstringsearch/Main2.java:[133,57] underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/javacodegeeks/jstringsearch/file/LuceneWriteIndexFromFileExample.java:[120,13] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
com/javacodegeeks/jstringsearch/memoryIndex/InMemoryLuceneIndex.java:[110,30] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

А у меня стоит версия 8.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как быть, или я что-то путаю? Как можно решать такую проблему?

Comment: То, что у вас Java8 не значит, что используются возможности Java8. В данном случае у вас все собирается как проект Java6. Отсюда и ошибки: в проекте используется функциональность, которая появилась только в Java7. Если вы скажете, чем вы собираете, то можно будет ответить, что именно нужно поправить

Comment: Проект запускаю через NetBeans, собираю проект через maven, подскажете как дальше мне быть в моей ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите в `pom.xml` что у вас исходники должны трактоваться компилятором как java7:

```
<project ...>
  ....
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  ...
</project.
```